# On delete CASCADE is not working in manyToMany mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have many to many mapping in hibernate with join table and have 3 different classes. `OperationEntity` and `EndPointEntity` has *manyToMany* mapping. I have tried using `@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)` and `@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` annotations. But when checked in Database, on delete and on update are RESTRICT. Below is the code:

OperationEntity.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="t_operation", schema="test")
public class OperationEntity implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="op_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int opId;

    @Column(name="op_name")
    private String opName;

    @Column(name="op_desc")
    private String opDesc;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="operationsEntity")
    private List<OpEndPointEntity> listOfOperationsEndpoints;   

    public int getOpId() {
        return opId;
    }

    public void setOpId(int opId) {
        this.opId = opId;
    }

    public String getOpName() {
        return opName;
    }

    public void setOpName(String opName) {
        this.opName = opName;
    }

    public String getOpDesc() {
        return opDesc;
    }

    public void setOpDesc(String opDesc) {
        this.opDesc = opDesc;
    }

    public List<OpEndPointEntity> getListOfOperationsEndpoints() {
        return listOfOperationsEndpoints;
    }

    public void setListOfOperationsEndpoints(
            List<OpEndPointEntity> listOfOperationsEndpoints) {
        this.listOfOperationsEndpoints = listOfOperationsEndpoints;
    }

}


    EndPointEntity.java

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="t_endPoint", schema="test")
    public class EndPointEntity implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @Column(name="end_point_id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int endPointId;

        @Column(name="end_point")
        private String endPoint;

        @Column(name="end_point_desc")
        private String endPointDesc;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="endPointEntity")
        private List<OpEndPointEntity> listOpEndPoint;

        public int getEndPointId() {
            return endPointId;
        }

        public void setEndPointId(int endPointId) {
            this.endPointId = endPointId;
        }

        public String getEndPoint() {
            return endPoint;
        }

        public void setEndPoint(String endPoint) {
            this.endPoint = endPoint;
        }

        public String getEndPointDesc() {
            return endPointDesc;
        }

        public void setEndPointDesc(String endPointDesc) {
            this.endPointDesc = endPointDesc;
        }

        public List<OpEndPointEntity> getListOpEndPoint() {
            return listOpEndPoint;
        }

        public void setListOpEndPoint(List<OpEndPointEntity> listOpEndPoint) {
            this.listOpEndPoint = listOpEndPoint;
        }
    }


    Mapping class : OpEndPointEntity.java

    import java.io.Serializable;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="t_op_endpoint_map", schema="test")
    public class OpEndPointEntity implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 71L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="OP_ENDPOINT_ID")
        private Integer operationEndpointId;

        @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="end_point_id")
        private EndPointEntity endPointEntity;

        @ManyToOne
        @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="op_id")
        private OperationEntity operationsEntity;

        public Integer getOperationEndpointId() {
            return operationEndpointId;
        }

        public void setOperationEndpointId(Integer operationEndpointId) {
            this.operationEndpointId = operationEndpointId;
        }

        public EndPointEntity getEndPointEntity() {
            return endPointEntity;
        }

        public void setEndPointEntity(EndPointEntity endPointEntity) {
            this.endPointEntity = endPointEntity;
        }

        public OperationEntity getOperationsEntity() {
            return operationsEntity;
        }

        public void setOperationsEntity(OperationEntity operationsEntity) {
            this.operationsEntity = operationsEntity;
        }

    }
```

Please provide a way to make on delete and on update CASCADE. Can it be jar issue?

Comment: Try adding `orphanRemoval = true` to the `@OneToMany` annotations.

Comment: It didn't work with orphanRemoval = true

Answer (score 0):

Did you delete it from Java code or using terminal? If you delete it from terminal, it won't work. Once you backup with mysqldump, you will see there's no ON DELETE SET NULL or ON DELETE CASCADE in that sql file. That means it works only with Java Code. Try deleting it from Java Code. I'm not sure how you delete it. And I need to see both classes to see the code.